# PHP processing of Flash submitted Form data, ModSecurity Error

Tags: php, image, flash

I'm using a PHP script to process form data from a Flash app.  This is the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
// create the target directory if it doesn't exist //   
   $dir = ($_GET['destination']) ? $_GET['destination'] : 'images';
   if (!file_exists($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0777, true);

// write the file to the target directory //        
   $fp = fopen($dir.'/'.$_GET['filename'], "wb" );
   fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
   fclose( $fp );   
}   
else{
    echo('file data not received');
}
?>
```

The file being written is an image, and the raw data is being sent by a Flash app.  There are three versions of the Flash app all being processed by this same piece of PHP.  Two of them process just fine; the third will process correctly about two times or so and then I start getting this error in the logs:

> > [Fri May 17 17:19:56 2013] [error] [client 172.251.78.205] ModSecurity: Error reading request body: Connection reset by peer [hostname "CLIENT URL"] [uri "/flash/php/saveImage.php"] [unique_id "UZbJGmFKGIcAAB37ctwAAABO"]

From what I have gathered, this means that the client connection is timing out before the form data is done being sent.  The other thing is that if I manually delete the directory that the image is being stored to and let the script create it will work every time.  I've been banging my head against my desk for hours. Can anyone can provide some insight as to what is going on and how I can resolve this issue?  If more information is required please let me know and I will provide you with whatever info you may need.  Thanks in advance.

I have tried using set_time_limit(0); and ignore_user_abort(true); but neither seem to have any effect.

Comment: What is the difference between the versions? Do they treat the data differently or use larger images, or...? What happens if you create a new dir for every image, just for testing. images/pictureone.jpg/pictureone.jpg

Comment: Tested this today.  Like before, I can go through about 2 until it starts throwing the Mod Security error.  However, unlike before if I wait a minute or so I can process 2 more posts until it errors out again.  Previously, it would just stop working completely.  So, progress?

Comment: Does anyone else have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to find the problem and a solution.  I was calling 2 php scripts in succession, one to save the image to disk and one to add the item to the shopping cart.  What was happening is that the shopping cart script was firing before the image saving one had finished and would halt it's process.  What I wound up doing in the end was adding a timed "Thank You For Shopping With Us" pop up in between the two PHP calls.  It only lasts for a couple of seconds, but it's just long enough for the image saving script to finish.  Haven't had any problems with it since.